# Angular 4 app - Client Caching for large data

Tags: json, angular, caching, client

Question: What is the best approach for implementing client caching of huge data. I am using Angular4 with Asp.net Web API2.

Problem: I am developing an web analytical tool (support mobile browsers as well) which generates echart metrics based on JSON data returned from Asp.net web api2. Web page have filters and chart events which recalculates charts measures based on same JSON data on client side. To optimize the speed, I have stored the JSON data(minified) in browser localstorage. With this I have avoiding frequent calls to api which are made on filter change and chart events. This JSON data is refreshed with server data at every 20 mins as I have set expiry for each JSON data saved on localstorage. 
Problem is localstorage has a size constraint of 10mb and above solution does not work when JSON data (multiple localstorage keys) exceeds 10mb.

Since my data size can vary and can go more than 10mb. What is the best approach to cache such data, as same data can be used for recalculating measures for metrics without making web api server calls.

I though about (below but not implemented yet), 
a) client- memory caching (may cause performance issues for users having less memory). 
b) Storing json data as a javascript variable and using it.

Please let me know better solution for large client cache.

Comment: searching for similar kind of solution